# 12 Month Average Except If Hire Date is Greater than start of year

Tags: sql

I'm successfully calculating a 12 month sales average for an employee based on the beginning and Ending of the year, in this case 2013. However, when an employee starts after the beginning of the year, their averages must start from their hire date. I need to figure out how to calculate the 12 month average for an employee who's hire date starts after the beginning of the year.

Here is my current query thus far:

```
    DECLARE @begDt DATETIME, @endDt DATETIME
    SET @begDt = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())), 0) 
    SET @endDt = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0))

  select
  [Account Executive] = v.Name_AccountExecutive
, [YTD Production] = cast(sum (case when v.Process_FundingDt between @begDt and @endDt then v.Loan_LoanAmt else 0 end) as int)
, [Monthly Average] = cast(sum (case when v.Process_FundingDt between @begDt and @endDt then v.Loan_LoanAmt else 0 end) 
  / (case when @begDt = '1/1/2012' then 
      case when v.Name_AccountExecutive = 'HIEB, BRANDON' then 7 when v.Name_AccountExecutive = 'AMORATI, KAREN' then 8 else 12 end
      else (datepart(m, @endDt)) end) as int)
from LOS.LoanView v
group by v.Name_AccountExecutive
```

Comment: If Bob is hired on March 2, 2012, should his average be for March 2, 2012 to December 31, 2012 or to March 1, 2013?

Comment: That should be until the end of year since I understand he's building a report.

Comment: lins314159, correct. The query i posted is for year to date. So if Bob is hired on March 2, 2013, his average will be from 3/2/2013 thru 05/31/2013(Today).

Comment: Guys i apologize. I relooked at the query and I pasted my monthly query and not my previous year. which didn't look at an average.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  You can use the OVER clause with AVG and use the ROWS subclause to calculate a 12 month moving average.  This is called Windowing Functions and is part of the ISO SQL Standard, but not all DBMSes support them.  Here is an example here using SQL Server 2012: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-2012-window-function-basics/

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys just wanted to answer this as I didn't form the question correctly and it just seemed confusing, buts heres the way I'm doing it. If theres a better way feel free to comment, but this works for now.

```
, [Monthly Average] = cast(sum (case when v.Process_FundingDt between @begDt and @endDt then v.Loan_LoanAmt else 0 end) as int)
/(case when aa.End_Date is NULL then 
      (
      case when Year(aa.Hire_Date)< Year(@begDt) and Year(@begDt)<Year(getdate()) then 12 -- hired anytime before the currrent reporting year and current reporting year is not current year.
            when Year(aa.Hire_Date) < Year(@begDt) and Year(@begDt)=Year(getdate()) then MONTH(getdate())-- hired  anytime before the currrent reporting year  and current reporting year is the current year
            when Year(aa.Hire_Date) = Year(@begDt) and Year(@begDt)<Year(getdate()) then 12-Month(aa.Hire_Date) -- hired same as reporting year but the reporting year is not same as current year
            when Year(aa.Hire_Date) = Year(@begDt) and Year(@begDt)=Year(getdate()) then MONTH(getdate())-Month(aa.Hire_Date) -- hired same as reporting year and the reporting year is  same as current year
      end
      )
      else
      (
      Case when Year(aa.End_Date)<Year(@begDt)  then NULL
            when Year(aa.End_Date)=Year(@begDt) and YEAR(aa.Hire_Date)<Year(aa.End_Date)  then MONTH(aa.End_Date) -- end date is same as reporting year, was hired preivous year, current year doesn't matter
            when Year(aa.End_Date)=Year(@begDt)and YEAR(aa.Hire_Date)=Year(aa.End_Date)  then MONTH(aa.End_Date)-MONTH(aa.Hire_Date) -- end year, start year and reporting year is same, current year doesn't matter
            when  Year(aa.End_Date)>Year(@begDt) and YEAR(aa.Hire_Date)=Year(@begDt) then 12-MONTH(aa.Hire_Date)
            when  Year(aa.End_Date)>Year(@begDt) and YEAR(aa.Hire_Date)<Year(@begDt) then 12
      end
      )
      end
)
```